# Conflicts between scrollTop and smooth anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a conflict between scrollTop (when i scroll appear divs) and the smooth anchor (when i click in menu, the anchor scroll quietly.)

But, this guys don't combine.

Example: When i click in some menu, and the anchor is after the element with scrollTop, the scroll stops in this element, and doesn't reach in the determined anchor.

I have this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 1500){
        $('#1993').fadeIn(1000).css({"display": "inline-block"});
    } else {

    };

    if($(this).scrollTop() > 1900){
        $('#2011').fadeIn(800).css({"display": "inline-block"});
    } else {

    };
});

/** SCROLL TO **/

 $('.goto').on('click', function(){
    var to = $(this).attr('href'); // $(this) is the clicked link. We store its href.
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: ($(to).offset().top)-1}, 850);
    return false;
});
```

Maybe the cause is the fadeIn?

Comment: FYI it is wrong to start ids with number such `id="1993"`

Comment: jsfiddle will be very useful.

Comment: @laaposto Thank you, Fixed, but the problem still going.